# REACTJS - How to load images in a Single-Spa microfrontend built with CRACO?

Tags: reactjs, image, micro-frontend, single-spa, craco

I have a microfrontends application in REACT JS managed with Single SPA. All our MFE are built with webpack and created with CRA.
We now want to migrate all of them to CRACO. Everything works, except for the static assets, that take the wrong URL.

By doing

```js
import OuterSpace from '@Img/pict-space.png
[...]
console.debug(OuterSpace);
<img src={OuterSpace} />;
```

I correctly see in the console that the path is `static/media/pict-space.2f39435387dcdab3b797.png`, but the resulting url for the image doesn't start from my MFE root (which is `http://localhost:3004`) but takes all the url of the window.

For example: if the current route is `http://localhost:3000/backoffice/1234-5678-9012/list`, the computed url for my image is `http://localhost:3000/backoffice/1234-5678-9012/list/static/media/pict-space.2f39435387dcdab3b797.png`, that of course is a `404 not found`.

How to manage this?

Comment: Line one has `@Img` which I assume means you are using aliasing to reference assets. You said that 'static/media/pict-space.2f39435387dcdab3b797.png' is the correct url, but that url you showed is always going to be relative to the URL of the page.  How to resolve depends on where you expect those files to exist at runtime.  I'd suggest updating your Alias to include a '/' before 'static' to indicate that the image isn't relative to the page, but is instead on the root of the site.  I don't think this is Single-SPA related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only sensible solution, in my opinion, is to set a proxy in the server for the root-config project.  This proxy would take requests for other microservices and would route them to the appropriate HTTP servers.  This requires a base path to be configured for each MFE so URL's can be differentiated.

If you are working with K8s, you are in luck:  K8s is already equipped with proxies.  Just define your ingresses for the MFE's using the base paths you set for each MFE and you're done.